# Imprimindo a média

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer um cálculo da média entre 2 valores, mas na hora de imprimir ele está imprimindo errado, no que eu estou errando?

```
var p1 = Number ('7.0')
var p2 = Number ('9.3')

const media = 2 / (p1 + p2)


if (media > 5.9) {
    console.log("Aprovado")
} else {
    console.log("Reprovado")
};
```

Comment: O que está errado? Como devia estar? Como está saindo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto é somar primeiro e dividir e não ao contrário:

`const media = (p1 + p2) / 2`

Senão o resultado seria 2 divido por 16.3, que dá 0.12.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var p1 = Number ('7.0')
var p2 = Number ('9.3')

const media =  (p1 + p2) / 2


if (media > 5.9) {
    console.log("Aprovado")
} else {
    console.log("Reprovado")
};
```

Comment: mas pq a ordem altera o resultado? numa equação nao sao as coisas dentr odo parenteses que sao resolvidas primeiro? e porque o 2 / estando na frente ele imprime reprovado? Grata desde ja <3

Comment: Mas você quer dividir a soma por 2 ou 2 pela soma?

Comment: Não é uma questão de ordem é uma questão de como foi montada a expressão. Veja que 2/10 é totalmente diferente de 10/2, certo? Mesmo que haja parênteses, por exemplo:  2 / (5+5) é diferente de (5+5) / 2. Se é uma média você soma os valores e divide depois

Comment: Se você tem 2 maças e divide para 16 pessoas, cada um receberia 0,125 partes da maça (isso porque há mais pessoas do que maça). Se você tem 16 maças e divide para 2 pessoas, então cada pessoa receberia 8 maças. A o valor altera conforme a ordem.

Comment: Correto @ValdeirPsr outro bom exemplo

Comment: ai mds é vdde kkkk, brigada gentee

Answer (score 1):

Ele está imprimindo certo porque 2 divididos por 7+9.3 sempre vai dar média menor que 5.9.

**veja seu código sendo executado**

```js
var p1 = Number ('7.0')
var p2 = Number ('9.3')

const media = 2 / (p1 + p2)

console.log(media);


if (media > 5.9) {
    console.log("Aprovado")
} else {
    console.log("Reprovado")
};
```

**O correto é o inverso dessa divisão, veja**

```js
var p1 = Number ('7.0')
var p2 = Number ('9.3')

const media = 1/(2 / (p1 + p2))

console.log(media);


if (media > 5.9) {
    console.log("Aprovado")
} else {
    console.log("Reprovado")
};
```

**Complicado?**

como no denominador possui uma fração, então, usamos aquela conhecida regra:

repete o primeiro e multiplica pelo inverso do segundo, ou seja, repete o numerador e multiplica pelo inverso do denominador.

```
     p1+p2
1 x _______ = (p1+p2)/2
       2
```

> não vão dizer que minha resposta é igual as outras não heim :D

Answer (score 0):

Parece-me uma questão de matemática. Soma primeiro e divide depois. Sugiro usar a função `parseFloat` do JavaScript para os valores `n1` e `n2` ao invés do `Number`

```js
var p1 = parseFloat(7.0)
var p2 = parseFloat(9.3)

const media = (p1 + p2) / 2


if (media > 5.9) {
  console.log("Aprovado")
} else {
  console.log("Reprovado")
};
```

Comment: Por que ele usar a função `parseFloat` ao invés da classe `Number`?

Comment: tbm quero saber aaaaa explica pra gente please <3

Comment: Eu prefiro usar parseFloat pq se tiver QQ carácter não número ele já faz o tratamento.

Answer (score 0):

O código foi feito corretamente, somente a ordem do divisor estava errado.
Quando colocou a divisão com (2 / numero da soma) o divisor é o numero da soma (maior que o numero a ser dividido) no caso deveria ser ao contrario 0 (numero da soma / 2), então 2 seria o divisor. Dai sim é possivel caso contrario sempre será zero ou esses quebrados em caso de numero real como usado.